# How can I do color correction for my images?

Tags: image-processing, colors, camera, calibration, generative-adversarial-network

Having ordered 4 cameras online for a project I notice that the colors on the output images are not consistent.  How can I compensate for these images and have all the images to be the same color? Is there any method that can fix this issue?
Please note that the background of my images is the same. However, the foreground is changing as my objects have different colors and shapes.

I found Adrian's (pyimagesearch) attempt to solve a very similar problem in the following link

[Fast Color Transfer](https://github.com/jrosebr1/color_transfer)

But the thing is that in my problem the colors of objects vary from one image to another, so I do not know how to reference image. 
Please advise!

Edited: suppose that I could not do color calibration using cameras, I only have images from those cameras, is it possible to do this at the post-processing stage using images only?

Comment: Google “color calibration”. This usually involves a color target that you image with each camera to determine the proper calibration factors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I have done some work, I edited my post please review it.

Comment: I wouldn't use color transfer. I'm talking about this type of stuff: https://camerajabber.com/how-to-calibrate-camera-colour/

Comment: This is an example of the color target you'd have to buy: https://www.amazon.com/X-Rite-ColorChecker-MSCCC-Photography-Filmmaking/dp/B000JLO31C

Comment: @CrisLuengo, suppose that I could not do color calibration using cameras, I only have images from those cameras, is it possible to do this at the post-processing stage using images?

Comment: Then the best you can do is find the correction that makes the background the same in all these images, since that is the one thing that doesn't change. What is in the background?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, the background doesn't have important information, the foreground info is important for me, the color of objects passing by.

Comment: Yes, by finding a correction factor that makes the background color match a standard, you correct the object colors too. Not as well as you could do with a color target, but it's better than no correction at all. It will likely amount to not much more to white balance correction, but that is a big step all in itself.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, where I can read more about this subject and get familiar with the code? Do you know what this method is called? can you please introduce some references so that I can read?

Comment: You can try enabling auto white balance and auto exposure time if your cameras support them, I mean, if they are the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are unable to take images of a color target for proper color calibration of the camera, the best you can do is a form of white balancing to at least remove the differences in illumination color and simple camera biases from your setup. This will not make the colors exactly the same across your cameras, but they will be a lot closer than simply using the raw images.

The idea is to take a common patch (for example a specific area of the background, which is consistent in your setup), and scale each of the three channels of the image such that this patch has a predefined color.

Let's say you have a gray background. You can find a portion of the background and measure the mean RGB values there. This leads to, for example, `[100, 120, 115]` in one camera. You want this to be gray, for example `[110,110,110]`. So you multiply each channel by the right factor: `110/100` for red, `110/120` for green, and `110/115` for blue. For the second camera, the same patch is `[110, 100, 95]`. Images from this camera you need to multiply by `1`, `110/100` and `110/95`.

In principle you only need to determine these factors once, leading to fixed corrections for each camera, assuming that the illumination doesn't change and everything else is under control as well. If there's a window that contributes to the illumination, you'll have to re-calibrate frequently, preferably for each image recorded. In this case you need to find an automated method to identify the background patch that you use for calibration.